# Grails instantiates object and uses in Controllers

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I have an application where it needs to instantiate only one object, I was thinking of Singleton, but before I jump in to that, I was thinking of dependency injection. What I would like to do is, to instantiate the object and `setAttribute` to `ServletContext` in `Bootstrap.groove` and use the object in every controller. My understanding would be that bootstrap will be called just once during the application lifetime? Could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define singleton beans in resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    myBean(my.company.MyBeanImpl) {
        singleton true
    }
}
```

then in your controllers

```
class ExampleController {
     def myBean
}
```

All documented here: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html