# How to implement user preferences in a Grails application

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm pretty new to Grails and am building an application. I've got a well-defined set of domain classes and controllers which are working quite well so far, but I now have a need to add some user preferences and settings, which I'd like to be able to access from any of the controllers. What's the best, most Grails-like way to achieve this?

Example: I have a RequestController which accepts uploaded files and saves them to a local directory which is set in the Settings object. Within this method, how can I get at that object?

```
def save() {
    String fileStoragePath = Settings.get(0).fileStoragePath // How do I do this?
    def requestInstance = new Request(params)
    def uploadedFile = request.getFile('payload')
    if (! new File(fileStoragePath).mkdirs()) {
        // TODO: Handle this error condition appropriately
    }
    if (uploadedFile && !uploadedFile.empty) {
        uploadedFile.transferTo(new File(fileStoragePath, uploadedFile.originalFilename))
        requestInstance.files << uploadedFile.originalFilename
    }
```

While I'm sure I can just make something work, I'd rather do it within the idiom, if at all possible. I keep finding Java syntax sneaking into my Groovy, and scrub regularly to get rid of it as it crops up....

Update:

I've also seen here ([Grails instantiates object and uses in Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716551/grails-instantiates-object-and-uses-in-controllers)) that it's possible to define a bean as a singleton and have it accessible from everywhere. Is that possible here? Or would doing that mean that I lose the ability to present that bean to the user through the usual Controller/View for configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Users have Preferences I would model this as a part my domain. Depending on your requirements Preferences could have well defined properties or simply be a collection of string key value pairs. From there I would either manually expose a UserPreferenceService in my controllers that need access to it (using dependency injection) or add it via meta programming to all controllers in Bootstrap.groovy.

This way in any controller I could quite easily do:

```
String fileStoragePath = userPreferenceService.resolve('storage.path')
```

The above example assumes that current user resolution is done internally (likely using Spring Security).

Also by abstracting this into a service it can have caching applied to it, used in other services or tag libraries, and so forth.

Hope that helps give you some ideas.

Comment: Aha! I've been looking at services and wondering if this was going to be my first place where they'd be useful. I had coded up the Preferences object as basically a Bean with key/value pairs (as you suggested) because that did seem the most logical way to gather them together.

I'll have to read up a bit on Bootstrap.groovy to see what that's all about. As I said, I'm new to this and occasionally just need a pointer to the right page to RTFM. ;-)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. If you need any pointers or other tips don't hesitate to ask (create a chat). I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Careful with caching as services are instantiated as singletons by default.  As this is user preferences you may wish to add in user ident to any method calls, e.g. `userPreferenceService.resolve('private.info', user)`

Comment: Depends on how you implement the cache, but you are right. If it's based upon method call then you would need to make it include the user.